# Can't close Image Picker in View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to display the image picker when the user enters into `ViewControllerA` and stay there after the user made a photo and pressed "Use Photo" button.

Actually the problem comes out when the user tap the "Use Photo" button, in this case the image picker pops up again time after time. I know it's because the `viewWillAppear`, but the `viewDidLoad` also not a good choice, because in this case the image picker won't be appear more than 1 time.

Possibly somebody could give me some guidance that how can I close the image picker without this issue? I just want to display it everytime the user enters in the view controller and close it after the user has choosen an image.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    self.imagePicker.delegate = self;
    self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;

    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
        self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;  
    } 
    self.imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage];

    [self presentViewController:self.imagePicker animated:NO completion:nil];
}

- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    UIImage *choosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    self.placeholderImg.image = choosenImage;
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}

- (void) imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1]; 
}
```

Comment: Call `dismiss...` on `picker` instead of `self`.

Comment: @rmaddy I call it in `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:`, or I should do it elsewhere?

Comment: Simply replace `[self dismiss...` with `[picker dismiss...`.

Comment: @rmaddy Unfortunately it doesn't help. It's the same.

Answer (score 0):

In your view controller's .m file you can declare a `BOOL` that will keep up if you've presented the `UIImagePickerController` already.

```
@interface MyCustomViewController ()
{
   BOOL imagePickerHasBeenPresented;
}

@end
```

And then in your `viewWillAppear` method check that bool:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if (imagePickerHasBeenPresented == NO)
    {
        imagePickerHasBeenPresented = YES;
       //Code to present imagePicker
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried it, but unfortunately when I go to ViewControllerB and  then go back to ViewControllerA the BOOL is still YES and the picker is not presented.